# check textbox's content has changed

Tags: javascript

In my form, I have 2 textbox (txtDate, txtTime), 1 hidden textbox (txtDateTime) and Save button. I want value of txtDateTime = txtDate + txtTime and it will automatically change value if user change at txtDate or txtTime.

How can I achieve this ? if you know, pls suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onchange` event like this:

```
var ttime = document.getElementById('txtTime');
var tdate = document.getElementById('txtDate');
var tdt = document.getElementById('txtDateTime');

ttime.onchange = function(){
  tdt.value = tdate.value + ttime.value;
};

tdate.onchange = function(){
  tdt.value = tdate.value + ttime.value;
};
```

Make sure to assign `id` attribute to your text boxes eg `txtTime`, `txtDate` and `txtDateTime`

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz, it works quite OK. But I don't understand why at the first time if I change at txtDate, value of txtDateTime still not yet change. For the second time it change good. With my code, I already added onchange="changeDatetime();" for two input box (txtDate, txtTime). What am I missing for ?

Answer (score 0):

Use onchange

```
<input type='text' onchange='change()' />

function change() {
    //code
}
```